# How do i get leap year work in this javascript time script

Tags: javascript, jquery, time, leap-year

Here i have a little script that gives me the passed time from a date until todays date, if time is over todays day it count down and vise versa.

Anyways my question is how i implant so it works correct whit leap years and stuff as it miss that part, but besides from that i think its quite good coded

```js
// JavaScript Timer
$(document).ready(function () {

  s("Time");

  function s(id) {

    var el = document.getElementById(id);
    var time = new Date("2001/01/29 13:19:00")

    var calc = function(t) {

      var now = new Date();

      var timestamp = Math.round(Math.abs(t.getTime() - now.getTime())/1000);
      var times = [60*60*24*365, 60*60*24*30, 60*60*24*7, 60*60*24, 60*60, 1*60];
      var resp = [];

      for (var i=0; i < times.length; i++) {
        resp.push(Math.floor(timestamp/times[i]));
        timestamp = timestamp % times[i];
      }

      resp.push(Math.floor(timestamp));

      var s = "";

      var meta = ["y", "m", "w", "d", "h", "m", "s"];
      var space = ""

      for (var i=0; i<meta.length; i++) {
        if (resp[i] > 0) {
          s += resp[i]+space+meta[i]+(resp[i] > 1 && meta[i].length > 1 ? "s" : "")+" ";
        }  
      }

      el.innerHTML = s + "ago"

      setTimeout(function() {calc(t)}, 1000);
    };

    calc(time);

  }
});
```

Here is a link to my [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Slaktarn/q5D8E/)

Thanks for any help you can use JavaScript/jQuery anything will work

/ Whiskey

Comment: Javascript's Date object is rather broken... you should look into http://momentjs.com/

Comment: @JeremyJStarcher How is it "broken"?

Comment: @Juhana [Link 1](http://codeofmatt.com/2013/06/07/javascript-date-type-is-horribly-broken/) [Link 2](http://gurustop.net/blog/2011/10/18/javascript-date-object-string-format-utc-iso-timezone/)

Comment: momentjs can´t do what i do whit this what i know, not whit an exact time i have check it, if anyone would know how you free to show me, is this thing broken or not? It works i think whit out the timeleap what i know